# how to change a value in an array?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the following code (in which I can only use HTML and PHP) whose objective is to change the letter of each cell, according to the operation performed on the form and displayed on the same page; The problem is that it is not fulfilling its objective, it tried in several ways but none of them worked; Could someone please help me?

**code 1:** *index.php*

```
<body>
    <center>
        <?php
            require('action.php');

            tables();
            actions();

            echo '<form>';
            echo '<label>Row: <input  name="row" method="post"></label><br/>';
            echo '<label>Place: <input name="place" method="post"></label><br/>';

            echo '<br/>Operation: <select name="select">';
            echo '<option>reserve</option>';
            echo '<option>buy</option>';
            echo '</select>';
            echo '<button type="submit" name="btn" formmethod="post">send</button>';
            echo '</form>';
        ?>
    </center>
</body>
```

**code 2:** *tables.php*

```
<?php
    function tables(){
        $seating = array(
            array('', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
            array(1, 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'),
            array(2, 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'),
            array(3, 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'),
            array(4, 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'),
            array(5, 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L')
        );
        echo '<table style="border: 1px solid black;">';
        for ($i=0; $i < 6; $i++) {
            echo '<tr>';
            for ($j=0; $j < 6; $j++) {
                echo '<td>'.$seating[$i][$j].'</td>';
            }}
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</table>';
    }
?>
```

**code 3:** *action.php*

```
<?php

    require('tablas.php');

    function actions(){
        if(isset($_POST["btn"])){
            if ($_POST["select"]=="reserve") {
                    $asientos[$_POST["row"]][$_POST["place"]]="R";
            }elseif ($_POST["select"]=="buy") {
                    $asientos[$_POST["row"]][$_POST["place"]]="L";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hello Tux9000. Welcome to stack overflow. This site does not help with debugging your code. Instead you should make the simplest example code possible, to explain your question. And ask a very precise question. Please rewrite your question.

Comment: thanks, I've already edited

Comment: Your `actions()` is never called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a form without `method`, so it defaults to GET, but you're using POST. You have some kind of method in the button, but that's incorrect:

```
<!-- This: -->
<button type="submit" name="btn" formmethod="post">send</button>

<!- Should be: -->
<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="btn">send</button>
</form>
```

---

This following is more of a code review, I'll edit it a few times as your code has room for improvement:

- Dont use `<center>`. Thats obsolete, try `<div style="text-align: center">`
- Your while form is now an echo in PHP. It's messy and this way you're missing the benefits of code coloring, such as is in answer. You can do this:

  ```
  ?><!-- Stop here, continue as html -->
  <form method="post">
      Your other inputs here
      <input name="example" value="See my pretty colors?" />
      <!-- well, it's weird here on SO, but you get the gist -->
  </form>
  <?php
  ```
- A function should not echo information, instead it should build a bit of html and return that. This'll create more manageble code where you can control what happens better.

  ```
  function tables(){
      $resulthtml = '';
      $resulthtml.= '<table style="border: 1px solid black;">';
      for ($i=0; $i < 6; $i++) {
          $resulthtml.= '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td></tr>';
      }

      return $resulthtml;
  }
  echo tables();
  ```

I'm going to leave it at this, as this is not a review site, but the above mentioned suggestions should help make your code cleaner, easier to understand and via extention easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

one typo I could see in **action.php** is:

require('*tablas.php*');

It should be:
    require('*tables.php*');

Comment: Yes, thank you, it was a typo, but there is no change, That was not the problem